# What is the meaning of the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> "I don't have a car, so I either cycle or walk most places."

Does it mean that I cycle (or walk) through or to most places?

Comment: *In principle* the speaker might intend to be pointing out that ***when he is at** [most places]* he cycles / walks around. But *in practice* that's an unlikely thing to say, so most people would naturally assume he means he cycles / walks ***in order to get to those places***. For all we know, perhaps he walks many miles to get to the nearest town, then spends many hours traveling between different places in town, ***using taxis***. The exact "meaning" is in the ***context***, not the words themselves.

Answer (score 2):

A google search for that text shows that it is from a conversation called "Getting Around".

> D: I don't have a car, so I either cycle or walk most places. Sometimes I take the metro or a taxi if I'm going further, or if I'm out in the evening.

In that context, it means "**to** most places", if the places are close enough. It doesn't mean "through". To clarify, if the destination is close enough, he will cycle there or walk there, and then back home.